# Is there a package similar to \underbrace{} that can be used to illustrate counting digits/decimal places in a number?

Tags: mathtools, underbrace

I want to make something similar to the image below. A wave-like line that hops between each number with an arrow to point at a particular place.

[image: example]

In general, a wave-like line that works similar to `\underbrace` and `\underbracket`

To demonstrate, this is how I'd like the function to work

```
$0.\underbrace{00001}2$
```

---

This is what I have in mind regarding how such a package might work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{underwave} % an example function.

\begin{document}
$$2\underwave[<-]{0120}.2$$
$$1.\underwave[->]{1234}4$$
\end{document}
```

This would create two illustrations, where the numbers will have a wave-like arrow pointing in either direction similar to the aforementioned image.

Comment: Rather show what code you'd use to achieve the picture. Also, I assume you want the wave-like pattern to go either way (left and/or right).

Comment: Yes, something like that. I've added some code that shows how a similar package would work (I don't know if that's is useful). I just want to know if there is a package that does this. Because I've seen this wave-like illustration in many textbooks. Especially, in topics where decimal point shifting is involved.